# Unable to update watchOS. Always paused

Tags: apple-watch, watchos

I can't pair an old Apple Watch Series 4. It always stuck at Software Update page and the download is always paused with message "You can resume the download when you are connected to a Wi-Fi network". But my iPhone is on a WiFi network.

I tried with two different iPhone, one with iOS16 and one with iOS17 and both having exact the same issue.

I tried to reset and restart the process countless times and restart both Apple Watch and iPhone and always the same result.

Both devices are always connected to a charger.

What can I change or do to attempt to complete this pair and update?

Comment: Did you try a [hard reset](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204567#:~:text=Put%20your%20watch%20on%20its,tap%20Reset%20again%20to%20confirm.)?

Comment: @IconDaemon the watch is already reset & unpaired. also it looks like is the watch app on iPhone having issue, not really related to the watch itself.

Comment: Apple support can enable diagnostic logs and perhaps help. Would you be willing to reach out to them? As long as any device is remotely within support, I’ve had good luck getting their help with an old watch.

Comment: @bmike what will be the best way to get support for this?

Comment: I start with the [support app on my iPhone / iPad](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/apple-support/id1130498044) but you could call, use the web site support.apple.com or visit a store if those work better for you @BryanChen

Comment: Thanks. Will give it a try. I live in a country without Apple Store so that's not an option.

Comment: Contracted with apple support. Not getting anything useful and eventually suggested visiting an authorized service provider for diagnostic.